# Keepalived mcast_src_ip not working

Tags: linux, multicast, high-availability

I have 2 servers running keepalived with following IP configurations:

**Server1:**

- eth0 172.31.48.10

**Server2:**

- eth0 192.168.1.5
- eth0:1 172.31.48.8

When Server1 is MASTER, Server2 receives properly VRRP advertisements to 224.0.0.18 multicast address from source 172.31.48.10 (Server1 eth0 ip address).

However, when Server2 is MASTER, it sends VRRP advertisements from source address 192.168.1.5, regardless the **mcast_src_ip 172.31.48.8** statement on configuration file. Then Server1 become MASTER because it is unable to communicate to peer of a different subnet.

I'm using CentOS 6 official Keepalived release (keepalived-1.2.13-5.el6_6.x86_64) and also I tried compiling a newest version (1.3.6) of Keepalived and the problem persists.

What am I doing wrong??

Follow my Keepalived configuration (the same configuration file on both peers):

```
global_defs {
   smtp_server 127.0.0.1
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  mcast_src_ip 172.31.48.8
  advert_int 1
  interface eth0
  state BACKUP
  virtual_router_id 54
  priority 100
  nopreempt

  authentication {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass TestAuth
  }

  track_interface {
    eth0
  }

  virtual_ipaddress {
    172.31.48.89/24 brd 172.31.48.255 dev eth0 label eth0:99
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `mcast_src_ip`  to

```
unicast_src_ip x..x.x.x # Master server IP
    unicast_peer {
        x.x.x.x  # Backup server IP
    }
```

For more information follow this  [article](https://bits.enigmabridge.com/articles/2016-11/keepalived-high-available-setup.html)